# Laravel Shopify API Wrapper, refused the connection

Tags: laravel-5, shopify

I have a project on building a shopify app through **"embedded SDK"** The app was installed successfully but it does not redirect back to admin where the app should show the API call result. When I try to access the app that I installed the frame will just display **The server refused the connection.**

I used the joshrps/laravel-shopify-API-wrapper for my laravel project. This is my controller where I make a request to install the app http://pastebin.com/zEn96SWs , this is my redirect uri when the app is successfully installed:

```
Route::get('shopify',function(){
    $sh = App::make('ShopifyAPI',[
        'API_KEY'=>'a1568bd534e2e7a88b21d693bdc73afe',
        'API_SECRET'=>'b15f951478db59369da196e77ea23fb7',
        'SHOP_DOMAIN'=>'shinobishop.myshopify.com']);
    $code = Input::get('code');
    try`enter code here`
    {
        $accessToken = $sh->getAccessToken($code);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo '<pre>Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</pre>';
    }
));
```

I hope you can help me with this issue. Its my first time using shopify API on projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this in your controller:

```
        $authorize_url = $sh->installURL([
        'permissions' => array (
            'write_orders', 'write_products'
        ),
        'redirect' => 'https://dev.yourshopifystore.com/route/'
    ]);

    return Redirect::to($authorize_url);
```